# Can not scroll smoothly with mouse wheel

Tags: mouse, scrolling, scroll-wheel

When I scroll anywhere (in webpages, games, IDEs, etc.) sometimes an opposite scrolling occur.
**OS:** Windows 10 (64bit)
**Mouse:** Trust GXT 152
Already cleaned my mouse and tried different ports. Also I made a JavaScript snippet to see how many reverse scrolling events occur.

```js
var pos = 0, neg = 0;
window.addEventListener('wheel', e => {if (e.deltaY < 0) neg++; else pos++;})
```

After scrolling down through 150 paragraph of lorem ipsum and evaluating

```js
neg/(pos+neg)*100
```

I got that around 20.5% of scroll events are wrong.
Just to be clear, it is NOT limited to browsers, I just used JS to measure how bad the situation is.